# Skype update cannot find file

Tags: installation, skype, updates, chocolatey

Skype told me to update, but when executing the update, there's an error message

[image: Skype error message]

> A network error occurred while attempting to read from the file: C:\ProgramData\Skype{FC965A47-4839-40CA-B618-18F486F042C6}\SkypeSetup_7.28.0.101.msi

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This may happen with Skype being installed from [Chocolatey Update Manager](https://chocolatey.org/). The Skype update package is not located in the place where Skype is looking for, but in

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\skype\7.28.0.101\SkypeSetup_7.28.0.101.msi
```

instead. That way, Skype can't find it.

Copying that file from Chocolatey to

```
C:\ProgramData\Skype\{FC965A47-4839-40CA-B618-18F486F042C6}
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: Chocolatey is a Package Manager or Software Manager, but I've never heard it described as an Update Manager. :D